# como pasar datos de un block de notas a un label en c#?

Tags: c#

Hola me encuentro desarrollando un sistema que se conecta a una balanza digital esta cada vez que toma un peso lo guarda en un bloc de notas llamado `peso` que se gurda en `C:\romana peso.txt` lo que necesito es sacar la información de ese txt y pasarlo a un `label` en c# (nota: cada vez que recibe un nuevo peso se sobreescribe el valor. Actualmente tengo el `label` `peso` como fijo pero necesito que cambie cada vez que el bloc de notas cambie su valor).

```
public partial class inicio : Form
{

    public inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txt_bin.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ingresar todos los campos.");
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt_bin.Text, label1.Text);
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {

        }
    }

    private void txt_bin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
            {
               if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt_bin.Text, label1.Text);
                txt_bin.Text = "";

            }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f) { }

    }

    private void txt_bin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void btn_imprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberías agregar lo que tienes de código hasta ahora y que has intentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira yo el otro día tuve que hacer algo similar, te paso un código de ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Abrir_Txt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\prueba.txt", false))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = line.toString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El archivo no se puede leer");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Yo le puse **Label1** pero tu cambialo y también donde sale **D:\prueba.txt** pon la ruta de tu archivo, con esto estás leyendo linea por linea y el valor se lo asigno al label que yo quiera, te dejo una página donde puede ver cómo leer y escribir en archivos txt.

Para que cambie, podrías poner un botón que se llame "refrescar" y te permita leer el archivo y cargar el valor.

Saludos.

[CREAR, MODIFICAR Y LEER UN ARCHIVO .TXT O .CSV EN C#](http://emmanuel6987.wixsite.com/easynetstudio/crear-y-modificar-txt-en-c-sharp)

Comment: estimado me funciono a la perfección pero ahora lo necesito sacar desde la red  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("\\192.168.5.49\Romana\peso.txt", false)) pero me da error en los (\) al insertar solo uno.

Comment: podrías mostrarme el error que te sale?

Comment: me sale que no encuentra el archivo txt segun la ruta descrita de esta manera \\192.168.5.49\\Romana\\peso.txt y si la abro de una carpeta tampoco pero si lo abro de una carpeta de esta manera \\192.168.5.49\Romana\peso.txt si lo abre pero me da error en el código con los \. el error es que dice secuencia de escape no reconocida.

Comment: prueba con @"Data Sourse=192.168.5.49\Romana\peso.txt"